# Performance problem on an asynchronous first Load of a TabItem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, asynchronous

I have a performance problem with my application, when I load a TabItem (each TabItem is bound to a ViewModel, each ViewModel having a DataTemplate). To solve this problem, I use an asynchronous loading in ViewModel constructor :

```
public MyViewModel(MyObject entity)
    {
       // WpfContext it's my Dispatcher
       Task.Factory.StartNew(() => WpfContext.Invoke(() =>
                                   {
                                       //Initialisation
                                       LoadMyObject(entity);
                                   }));
    }
```

With this solution, the first time the TabItem is loaded, it takes some times and seems  not really asynchronous. For the other loads, it works good and asynchronously. I don't know exactly why. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

`Invoke` on a Dispatcher is a blocking call for both the background thread of your Task and then also the UI thread (once it decides to actually run your code).

It seems asynchronous sometimes because the UI thread is busy showing the new Tab, and so the `Invoke` from the background thread is blocking until the UI thread has time to process it.  When it seems like it is synchronous, the Invoke call is being processed by the UI thread *before* the new Tab is being displayed.  So, in the end, I think you have a race condition.

To resolve this, you may need to refactor your `LoadMyObject` method so it can be run on the background thread, or you could use the [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx) method and provide it a lower priority to ensure the display of your new Tab precedes the processing of the `LoadMyObject` call

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "you may need to refactor your LoadMyObject" ? When I use Task.Factory.StartNew to create a background task to call LoadMyObject nothing changed... I Also tried BeginInvoke but my TabItem stay empty.

Comment: Since I don't know what `LoadMyObject` actually does, I assumed it was a long running method that also caused eventing to tell WPF to update the display to render the new data.  I was thinking you could refactor this to do the long running parts on the background thread, and then invoke to the UI only when required.  Right now, starting the Task doesn't change anything, because it immediately calls `Invoke`, which just moves back to the UI thread.